# Error: Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Tags: mysql

This question might be a duplicate to these questions:

- [Failed to read auto-increment value from the storage engine in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125394/failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-the-storage-engine-in-mysql)
- [mysql Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346934/mysql-failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine)
- [Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine, Error Number: 1467](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690926/failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine-error-number-1467)
- [Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine. Cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957222/failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine-cause)

Anyhow, the solutions did not work for me, so it seems to be the same error but different cause.

Situation: In MySQL i have a table with one "id"-column (the primary key) which has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property set. Each time i try to insert a new row into that table i get the following error:

```
Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine.
```

In the questions mentioned above the solution was to reset the auto-increment value with:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

In my case this works fine as long as i don't reboot my computer. When i do, i'm getting the error again.

**Additional Information:**

Here is my `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `producer` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `setup_cost` double NOT NULL,
 `delivery_time` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `stock_delivery_time` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When executing `SHOW TABLE STATUS` i have recognized something weird: `Auto_increment` is set to 0 and `Create_time` is set to "2014-01-20 17:00:46" although i have created the table about a month ago.

I also checked for corrupted Data with the MySQL command `CHECK TABLE tablename EXTENDED` (thx @ToBe, see comments) but no errors were found.

Since I'm not very familiar with MySQL please tell me if I have forgot to provide any necessary information in the comments.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check for corrupt tables? There should be some tools for that in your mysql folders.

Comment: @ToBe Thanks for the tip I checked the table with the MySQL command `CHECK TABLE tablename EXTENDED` but no errors were found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because i solved it myself by dropping the table and recreating it. I had the same issue on some other tables and there i could solve it by only dropping the AUTO_INCREMENT from the column and redefining it.